# Struct points as parameter to function C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a few months that i started programming in C, but I now find myself with a doubt, for example, let see the next example code:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char *var1;
    }myFooStruct;

    myFooStruct struct1 [ 200 ];
```

my doubt is what would I get for **struct1, &struct1, *struct1, struct1,
as I passed the struct to a function that takes a two-dimenssion pointer ( **myFooStruct ), I have basic knowledge about pointers  **1-but I find myself confused with pointers to structs and 2-how can I modify the struct if I passed it as at parameter to a function**

If there is another similar question post it here please, I could not find anything alike, if you know some lecture I could read is welcome too, thank you very much!!

Comment: You typically cannot legally dereference a struct. If you have `myFooStruct struct0;` then `*struct0` is a syntax error. So therefore in your code `**struct1` is also a syntax error

Comment: Thanks Chris!.... Ok guys, I had a hard time choosing the answer, I choose the one that I find more complete to question in my point of view, thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is a *dereference operator* - think of it as meaning "the value contained at location xyz".

`&` is a *reference operator* - think of it as meaning "the location in memory of variable xyz".

Accordingly:

`myFooStruct struct1` is a physical structure - this is the actual object.

`&struct1` is equivalent to the location in memory of `struct1` - this is usually an address (like `0xf0004782`).  You'll usually see this used when *passing by reference* (see Wikipedia for more info) or when assigning to a *pointer* (which literally points to a location in memory - get it?).

`*struct1` *dereferences* `struct1` - that is, it returns the value contained at location `struct1`.  In the example you give, **this is invalid**, as `struct1` is not a pointer to a location in memory.

`**struct1` is tricky - it returns the value contained at the location that is contained within `struct1`.  In other words: `struct1` points to a certain location in memory.  At that location is the address of another location in memory!  Think of it as a scavenger hunt - you go to a location, find a clue, and follow that to another location.

---

As to how to access structs: think of a struct as a box. When you have the box in front of you, you simply need to open it up and look at what's inside. In C, we do this using the `.` operator:

`char *my_var = struct1.var1`

When you don't have the box in front of you - that is, you have a pointer to the struct - you need to access the location the box is at before you can look at what's inside.  In C, we have a shortcut for this - the `->` operator:

```
myFooStruct *pointer_to_struct1 = &struct1
char *my_var = pointer_to_struct1->var1
//NOTE: the previous line is equivalent to:
//  char *my_var = (*pointer_to_struct1).var1
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! complete and clean answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Way 1 Using dynamic memory allocation. Generally used in linked list and all..

If you want to modify the `struct` in another function. first declare a pointer to a `struct`.

```
myFooStruct* struct1;
```

Allot memory for the `struct`

```
struct1 = malloc(sizeof(myFooStruct));
```

Send the address to the function

```
func1(struct1);
```

Receive it and access it to modify in the function.

```
void func(myFooStruct* struct1)
{
    (*struct1).member1 = ...; // whatever you wanna do
    ...
```

> Way 2

Declare a `struct`.

```
myFooStruct struct1;
```

Send the address of the `struct` to the function

```
func1(&struct1);
```

Receive it and access it to modify in the function.

```
void func(myFooStruct* struct1)
{
    (*struct1).member1 = ...; // whatever you wanna do
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically allocate memory for struct? You do not have to do this to pass struct to another function

Comment: No that's fine. Just wanted to know if there is any reason to this :)

Comment: Thanks very much!, I didn't choose this answer only because you did not touch the **operand, but is very clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @Javi9207 No problem brother, its not about the points. Its about what you learn and how our effort helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access `myFooStruct` from function, you can define single pointer: `fn( myFooStruct * st )`. The you call the function with `fn( struct1 )` and change values `st[N].var1 = ...`. Double pointer may be necessary if your object is pointer with allocated memory, not static array as yours.

Answer (score 1):

`struct1` is just a table and to be speciffic it's just pointer to a place in the memory.

`*struct1` would be thing, that is pointed by struct1, so it's a first struct in a table of structs.

But `**struct1` won't be any string. First of all you do not allocate memory for string and second string is member of this struct not struct itself. **struct is undefined behavior, nothing more.

`&struct` is a pointer to the table, so it's a pointer to the pointer, that points first struct in a table.

You have to decide on your own, what you want. If you want to pass table of your structs then the cleanest way would be:

```
void function(myFooStruct structTab[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You should pass a `struct pointer` to function to access `struct` inside it .

Declare a struct pointer -

```
myFooStruct *struct1;
```

Allocate memory for `struct`

And pass it to function which is declared as -

```
 type fn(myFooStruct *struct1){
     .....
     }
```

Call this function like this -

```
fn(struct1);
```

Access struct member like this -`struct->member1`

**2.** You can also pass what you have declared right now.

```
myFooStruct struct1[ 200 ];
```

define function as -

```
type fn(myFooStruct struct1[]){
.....
}
```

Access struct members like this - `struct[i].member1`.